# What is the origin of the phrase "forty winks," meaning a short nap?

Tags: phrases, etymology

Inspired by the question *[How long is a 'wink'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/22500/5822)*, I did some work on the origin of the phrase *forty winks*. Though the OP at the *wink* question mentions the phrase, it does not ask about its origin. So I thought I'd ask the question here and post what I've found. I was able to find an antedating not mentioned by any of the usual phrase-dictionary suspects. The most accurate information I found elsewhere was from a [post](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?p=33068#p33068) by Ken G in a discussion of the phrase at Wordwizard. Any other insights welcome.

Comment: Interestingly, if you use "minutes" instead of "winks" it works fine. A 45 min. nap  is ideal

Comment: A synonymous expression is to "catch a few z's."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> William Kitchiner M.D. (1775–1827) was
>   an optician, inventor of telescopes,
>   amateur musician and exceptional cook.
>   His name was a household word during
>   the 19th century, and his *Cook’s
>   Oracle* was a bestseller in England
>   and America.

<sup>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Kitchiner)</sup>

The phrase *forty winks*, meaning a short nap, can be traced back to Dr. Kitchiner's 1821 self-help guide, *The Art of Invigorating and Prolonging Life*. The phrase is mentioned in a November 1821 issue of the British *Literary Chronicle*, in a [review](http://books.google.com/books?pg=PA738&dq=%22forty%20winks%22&ei=Qni1TfHZJKr50gGVubCkCQ&ct=result&id=X3QPAAAAQAAJ#v=onepage&q=%22forty%20winks%22&f=false) of Kitchiner's book:

> Sleep is a subject on which our author
>   acknowledges his feelings are
>   tremblingly alive; he is fond of a
>   'forty-winks' nap in an horizontal
>   posture,' as the best preparative for
>   any extraordinary exertion, either of
>   body or mind.

Here is a [clip](http://books.google.com/books?id=wD5KAAAAYAAJ&q=forty%20winks#v=snippet&q=forty%20winks&f=false) from an 1822 copy of Kitchiner's book:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=wD5KAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA69&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U05EQTfODD76gC5RYztbqke9PCOWg&ci=9%2C402%2C828%2C513&edge=0]

The use of quotes around *a forty winks nap* seems to indicate Kitchiner might have borrowed the phrase from elsewhere, but I can't find it in any form earlier than his use of it. Also, Kitchiner carefully footnotes other phrases and passages from different authors throughout his book.

Answer (score 3):

There was also the idiomatic expression ***nine winks*** in the mid 19th century.  Eric Partridge in his *The Routledge Dictionary of Historical Slang* claims that the term already existed in 1820. I found evidence to support this in John Badcock's: *[Slang: A Dictionary of the Turf, the Ring, the Chase, the Pit, of Bon-ton](http://books.google.it/books?id=HfUSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=%22nine%20winks%22&source=bl&ots=5UtMYofldN&sig=Bv0YT3SjjmjA8tkFq0Zjp2tUGCw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LX18U7WJLarmywOtuoLICw&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=winks&f=false)* printed in 1823. The *slang* term "forty winks" was not yet listed, which suggests that the idiom was either too new to have merited its own entry or had not yet been coined.

[image]

As the earliest recorded evidence of *forty winks* is found in 1822, it is most likely that John Badcock was unaware of its existence.  In light of this, Kitchiner was probably referring to the established *nine winks* phrase when he placed his (neologistic) "A Forty Winks Nap" in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

[Online Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=forty%20winks&searchmode=none) reports only that its usage was attested from 1828.

The expression had been used by Lewis Carroll in his novel *Sylvie and Bruno*, and  F. Scott Fitzgerald used it in a short article titled *Gretchen’s Forty Winks*.

Comment: Doug at Etymonline has updated his entry with my finding.