# What is the best literary technique to introduce a new word, conceived by yourself, in your story?

Tags: writing, writing-style

I am an aspiring novelist, and there's this "science fiction & fantasy" story I am working on, wherein I have coined some new words here and there.

I am sending this question to the proficient wordsmiths in the *stackosphere*, and beseech them to yield a proper way, say a literary technique, to introduce a brand new word without offending the multitudinous readers and publishers who maybe inclined to consider a word not included in Oxford Dictionary a heresy.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the Harry Potter books?  Do you think all the words are in the OED?

Comment: Every word has to be invented by someone; it might as well be a "qualified" wordsmith like a writer. Where would the English language be had Shakespeare not created words like _metamorphize_ or _invulnerable_ while composing his plays? It is also interesting to note that some currently established words like _scientist_ were initially dismissed as "vulgarisms" near the time of their origin. Don't let pedants prevent you from expanding the English language's vocabulary.

Comment: Yes, I have. And, yes, I get your point. You kinda hit me with an apapneo. Thanks, @RyeBread. That was a pretty good jinx.

Comment: @TheodoreBroda I couldn't agree more.

Comment: So, what would you say is the proper technique to introduce a new word?

Comment: Take an established Latin or Greek root, and add relevant affixes to them. This is especially useful for science fiction. One example is the term _xenomorph_ used in the _Alien_ movies to refer to the alien; it is a combination of the Greek _xeno-_ (meaning foreign) and _-morph_ (meaning form or manifestation).

Comment: PS: For fantasy novels, Latin is also useful. Just look at all the pseudo-Latin spell names in Harry Potter (Expelliarmus!).

Comment: Root and affixes. Wow! Thanks a ton, @TheodoreBroda.

Comment: This question is too broad and POB (primarily opinion based). Sorry.

Comment: @Mari-LouA While I agree with you, I must say that it takes thousands of identical opinions to create a fact. I was merely seeking the "unanimous" style for creating new words. Other commentators have been helpful in this matter. Perhaps you have a good opinion too?

Comment: I've given my opinion, and I've stated it too. I also upvoted Ryebread's comment. How many more answers do you need to receive before you are convinced that authors/writers/the-man-in-the-street can coin as many expressions as he sees fit? See this [post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22665/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-forty-winks-meaning-a-short-nap/171936#171936) for just one of many thousands of instances where new words/expressions have been created ad hoc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That was a well-researched and good argument you gave for the issue of "forty winks". I was looking exactly for such citations to my answer, especially for the proper way to introduce a new word, and not really about whether it's inappropriate. Anyways, I get your point. And, yes, RyeBread's answer is helpful.

Comment: Ask the "multitudinous readers and publishers" if they ever heard of "Shakespeare."

Comment: As for you, please visit [writers.se]

Comment: This question is better on [writers.se]

Comment: Great; someone discovered the breadcrumb I had dropped. Yes, @Kris, the reason I used the word "multitudinous" was solely to cite Shakespeare, who, as per the Oxford scholars, is the creator of that word and 1600 more.

Comment: @ RyeɃreḁd They probably are now.

Comment: Weren't a lot of Shakespeare's neologisms variants of his own name? With regard to credibility and possible success, Rowling had one or two strengths other than coining new words. If a writer / actor / comedian is considered good, their coinings will probably be accepted interfrastically.

Comment: @TheodoreBroda Of all, you have been the most helpful. Would you do me a favor and write that "root and affix" answer in the answer box, just so that I can put an end to this?

Comment: I would, but unfortunately, it looks like your question has been put on hold for the time being. Perhaps when the question is re-edited? I thought that your question prompted some useful and objective answers about the development of neologisms into established words (with interesting examples like _homeopape_ from @ThirdNews), but apparently some of the moderators disagree.

Comment: Alas, some people who call themselves moderator are quite opinionated. No wonder, my innocent question has been put on hold as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: Possibly, their actions were motivated by your use of the "illegitimate" word _stackosphere_; maybe such neologisms are too controversial for this site.

Comment: @TheodoreBroda - neologisms are not taboo at this site. Primarily Opinion Based questions are. Both of you should read the Help section to see what type of questions are on topic here.

Comment: Stackosphere was merely intended as an example of neologism, which is what my question is all about. Glad that you mentioned it. :) @TheodoreBroda

Comment: @TheodoreBroda Anyways, I have gone ahead and checked Third News' answer since you are not allowed to. I just want to put an end to this whole supposedly opinionated question. I thought the internet was open for expression but here also moderators rule.

Comment: I read through the help section, as suggested by @medica, and the site requires questions that can have conclusive answers; I guess that these kinds of question tends to provoke drawn-out debates. If you want, you could ask specifically how new words are added to the dictionary or otherwise become accepted (I still don't know if this would meet the moderators' criteria for the Q&A format, and you might have lost interest in defending your question at this point.)

Comment: I examined the Writers Stack Exchange _About_ page (as initially mentioned by @Kris), and your question seems quite appropriate for that site. However, I took umbrage at their blatant missing apostrophe in "Writers", which is clearly supposed to be possessive.

Comment: The thing is I have changed my question, and made it to say what literary style I should use when introducing a new word. And, I guess this question has a concluding answer. Or does it need to be further improved, @medica? Check my comment in the answer box. That was a concluding answer enough.

Comment: Do not change a question materially. We can post a separate new question when needed instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Science fiction writer Philip K. Dick didn't think so, and indeed did so.  My favorite is Dick's rather psychic neologism:  **[homeopape](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=637)**

> In a corner of the large room a chime sounded and a tinkling
>   mechanical voice called, "I'm your free homeopape machine, a service
>   supplied exclusively by all the fine Rootes hotels throughout Earth
>   and the colonies. Simply dial the classification of news that you
>   wish, and in a matter of seconds I'll speedily provide you with a
>   fresh, up-to-the-minute homeopape tailored to your individual
>   requirements; and, let me repeat, at no cost to you!"

Comment: Your example of homeopape is helpful. From it, I gather that if I were to conceive and insert a new word in my story, I will have to define this new word right after mentioning it. Now that's a literary technique I wanted to know about, besides the "root and affix" technique as provided in the comment section by @TheodoreBroda. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The history of English literature is bestrewn with neologizers. As well as the above-mentioned Shakespeare, other similarly inclined writers of note have included Edmund Spenser, John Milton, Anthony Burgess, James Joyce, Vladimir Nabokov, George Orwell and Charles Dickens; and there have been countless others besides. Scientists and technologists too are always creating new words as their fields of activity expand. (Not to mention the social scientists, economists and politicians.)

The upshot is that you should certainly not hesitate to invent new words if they fit a particular need. (Make them good ones!)

In addition to the technical process of generating a new word, there is the question of how to goose its popularity. For this I would suggest making use of your social network connections as and when the publication date draws near. If you can scare up some curiosity about the words your immediate contacts may encounter in your new book, they are more likely to buy the product of your labours.

Comment: Excellent (and extensive) examples! I do particularly appreciate Milton's _pandemonium_ and Orwell's _newspeak_; quite useful, if you ask me. Also of note, some words were derived from the works of these great writers, but were not directly coined by them; the characteristic expressions of Dicken's character "Sam Weller" were so witty, English speakers quickly created the word _wellerism_, which came about only a couple years after the _Pickwick Papers_.